# What is the best way to draw objects and deal with them?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

***Hi,***

I want to draw on my PictureBox and then deal with those drawings that i created.

is it a good way to store their points in an array and deal with this array??.

**Or the better way is to make them objects and deal with these objects?.**And if so could you please put me on the head of way to make that??.

Thank you my really teachers.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  elements of the drawing might change then an object (Shape) is best. But a collection of points is an object as well.

The main alternative would be a layered approach with a separate bitmap with a transparent background holding the points.

Comment: First of all thank u for your speedy reply,
Then:

the shapes will not very changed but I'll move them and resize them.

So what is the best way?.

Thanx

Comment: An object, which might contain a list of points if that convenient.